# Unit Testing Android using ActivityUnitTestCase and PreferenceManager

Tags: android, unit-testing, sharedpreferences

I have an `Activity` I am unit testing.  I want to test the `Activity` in isolation, so the [ActivityUnitTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html) fits my purposes very well.

The `onCreate` method of my `Activity` uses a value that is stored in the Preferences.  I would like to set a value for this in my test case.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to set the `Preference` ahead of time.  There is not a `getContext()` method in `ActivityUnitTestCase`, and `getActivity()`, which should return a `context`, is null until I call `startActivity()`.  This is not an option because calling `startActivity` will trigger the `onCreate` method, and this is where the preferences code lives.

Any thoughts on how I can get a `context` that I can use to manipulate the preferences for my unit tests?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the context via the instrumentation.

To get the Context of instrumentation (test runner):

```
getInstrumentation().getContext()
```

But you probably need the context of the instrumented application:

```
getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()
```

Comment: Hi, but in my case `getInstrumentation()` is returning **null**. I'm extending  `ActivityUnitTestCase`. Any idea?